ERROR Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSModalScreen" was not found in the UIManager
I have a managed workflow expo application and I was having this issue unexpectedly because I was following the docs of the react navigation. The issue was related to the tab navigator that I was using, the stack navigator was working fine (in my app I have nested navigators) but when I was switching to the Bottom tabs navigator it crashes the app and gives the error mentioned in the title.
After some research I tried downloading the react-screens library but it did not seem to work, I closed the running metro instance and went to react navigation docs I noticed a command
npx expo install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context
I installed the packages above but with expo cli and not npm, after a restart it was working fine. If someone has the same issue please relate to expo when installing core packages and not npm.
Happy Coding!
I tried creating a new project and setting up everything from scratch but it does not seem to work

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

same issue, only working with android.

this in insane, took me a while to find a solution, but as you mention, installing with npx expo install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context worked for me. Thanks!!

Maybe downgrade or upgrade to compatible package version. Check out the log for this (e.g.):
The following packages should be updated for best compatibility with the installed expo version: 
react-native-safe-area-context@4.9.0 - expected version: 4.8.2 
react-native-screens@3.30.1 - expected version: ~3.29.0 
Your project may not work correctly until you install the correct versions of the packages.

In this case I would run the following commands to downgrade:
npm install react-native-safe-area-context@4.8.2
npm install react-native-screens@~3.29.0

Hope this helps!

Thanks. I had the same error with "react-native-screens": "^3.30.1", switched batch to "react-native-screens": "~3.29.0" and it worked

Good to hear. You're welcome!

Thank you! that helped. I didn't know that using newer version could have such effect on the app

This issue is caused by the libraries (react-native-screens and react-native-safe-area-context) not installed properly. Just run the following command (if you're using expo):
npx expo install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context

and if you're using bare React Native project:
npm install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context

and rebuild the project.
In my case, this worked fine.

Try to install same version of react-native-screens and react-native. It might fix your issue.

I had the same issue, although installing screens and safe area context solved it for me. I think there's a version problem with screens that might be worth looking into

I was able to fix my dependency issues by running expo doctor --fix-dependencies to align all my depencies to a compatible version.
Here's some documentation on the command
